# Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC when trying to add formula r1c1 while creating workbook

Tags: c#, .net, excel-formula, excel-interop, vlookup

I am creating an Excel file using C#.

The end result should be:

1. Excel workbook with 5 sheets
2. 1 sheet is generated using other 4 sheets.
3. 4 sheets are generated from database
4. All the formulas should be added to sheet 1 just in case the user wants to add data manually to other 4 sheets

I am stuck at:

After I create all the 4 sheets, I am trying to add formulae to sheet 1.

Formula Logic - Look for value of column A (all rows one by one) of sheet 1 (current) in sheet 2's column A, and get the value of column K of that row.

I am trying to add the below VLOOKUP to the 12th row and will copy the formula to all rows.

```
oRng = worksheet.Range["J12"];
oRng.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(RC[-9],'Sheet2'!$A:$K,11,0)),'',VLOOKUP(RC[-9],'Sheet2'!$A:$K,11,0)";
```

But I get the error:

> Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC

Comment: I am not saving the excel till this point.

Comment: Did either of the suggested answers fix your problem, or did you fix it another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are:

- Mixing A1 and R1C1 style (which it doesn't like)
- using `''` instead of `""` (which it doesn't like)
- using `$` for absolute references on A1 style references in `FormulaR1C1` (which it doesn't like)

**edit** it seems less likely in your case as you've said the formula works with direct input, but you may also have a locale issue where excel wants semicolon list separators and you are using commas, see [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16777719/1945631) for a solution to that. (end edit)

So try:

```
oRng.Formula = @"=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(A12,Sheet2!$A:$K,11,0)),"""",VLOOKUP(A12,Sheet2!$A:$K,11,0))";
```

or

```
oRng.FormulaR1C1 = @"=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(RC[-9],Sheet2!C1:C11,11,0)),"""",VLOOKUP(RC[-9],Sheet2!C1:C11,11,0))";
```

(If you don't want to prefix your string with `@` then change all `""` to `\"` inside the string)

*Footnote*

You can shorten your formula to this in later versions of Excel (2007 onwards):

```
oRng.Formula     = @"=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A12,Sheet2!$A:$K,11,0),"""")"
oRng.FormulaR1C1 = @"=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC[-9],Sheet2!C1:C11,11,0),"""")"
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the correct number of parenthesis in your Excel formula : you are missing one at the end.

Comment: Thanks Boud! I thought that was the end of my misery. But still no luck. Still getting the same error.