# Cells.Formula="=CONCATENATE(...)" Exception 0x800A03EC

Tags: vb.net, excel, exception, concatenation, excel-interop

I'm writing a VB.NET application that generates an Excel file.

My intention here is to write a particular formula that uses `CONCATENATE` in a cell.

Now, the following line of code fires the above exception:

```
0) tSheet.Cells(tIncRow + ItemIndex * PixelIndex + PixelIndex, 2).Formula = 
   "=CONCATENATE(" & Pixels(PixelIndex) & ";Batches!J3)"
```

The following row does NOT raise the exception. (It's simply the row above without the `=` at the beginning. The fact that it doesn't raise the exception means that the indexes are used properly; I'll get rid of them in the following passages to ease the notation). Also, if I manually put in Excel an `=` in front of the very same formula, then the formula gives a correct result (it correctly grabs `Batches!J3`)

```
1) tSheet.Cells(tIncRow + ItemIndex * PixelIndex + PixelIndex, 2).Formula = 
   "CONCATENATE(" & Pixels(PixelIndex) & ";Batches!J3)"
```

The following line also runs without problem:

```
2) tSheet.Cells(indexes).Formula = "=CONCATENATE(" & Pixels(PixelIndex) & ")"
```

This line works as well:

```
3) tSheet.Cells(indexes).Formula = "=CONCATENATE(Batches!J3)"
```

It seems that only the combination of 2) and 3) raises the exception.

I'm using Visual Studio 2012, Excel 2007, and I'm including Microsoft Excel 12.0 Object Library

Thanks for any help!

Comment: What is the value of `Pixels(PixelIndex)`? This error code is very general, and can mean anything from a mis-written formula, to a missing name, mixing of R1C1 and A1 styles etc.

Comment: Also, what language are you using in Excel? Do you separate arguments with comma (`,`) like the UK english version, or semicolon (`;`) like the european version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't mentioned your locale, so just in case Excel is expecting argument separators to be comma (as in the en-UK locale) instead of semicolon (as in de-DE locale) then try:

```
tSheet.Cells(tIncRow + ItemIndex * PixelIndex + PixelIndex, 2).Formula = 
    "=CONCATENATE(" & Pixels(PixelIndex) & ",Batches!J3)"
```

(edit) If that does work, then you can use something like the following to make it locale independent:

```
Dim ci As CultureInfo = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture
Dim listSep As String = ci.TextInfo.ListSeparator
tSheet.Cells(tIncRow + ItemIndex * PixelIndex + PixelIndex, 2).Formula =
    "=CONCATENATE(" & Pixels(PixelIndex) & listSep & "Batches!J3)"
```

That just grabs the numeric list separator from the windows culture. It does assume that Excel runs with `System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture`, see the following two MSDN references for more detailed information on this and the special cases you may encounter:

- [Creating Excel Solutions for Use in Multiple Countries/Regions Using Visual Studio Tools for Office](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa537159%28v=office.11%29.aspx#officevstoglobalization_writecodetocheckregionalsettings) (espcially the "Writing Code to Check Regional Settings" section)
- [Creating Office Solutions for Use in Multiple Countries/Regions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa168494%28v=office.11%29.aspx)

(end edit)

If this doesn't work, then we might need more info - see my comments on your original question.

Comment: Hello! Thank you very much for the detailed answer! First of all I won't be able to test your corrections until tomorrow morning (CEST time), but let me add that you could actually be right: you've seen through the fact that there is a mismatch between "locales" of my Excel version and my Visual Studio one. In fact Excel is in European locale (";") while Visual studio should be in en-US. If some sort of Validation of the formula entered is run also by Visual Studio, than  it could clearly explain the Exception.
I will be pleased to include additional information if this solution doesn't work!

Comment: Man, you were right! I put the comma in the VB.NET code and when it copied the Formula in Excel it changed it back in a semicolon. Thank you!